# Avoid calling omp_get_thread_num() in parallel for loop with simd

Tags: c++, openmp

What is the performance cost of call omp_get_thread_num(), compared to look up the value of a variable?

How to avoid calling omp_get_thread_num() for many times in a simd openmp loop?

I can use `#pragma omp parallel`, but will that make a simd loop?

```
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a(100);
    auto a_size = a.size(); 
    #pragma omp for simd
    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; ++i) {
        a[i] = omp_get_thread_num();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the actual code, the part where autovectorization should help uses openmp's thread id for domain decomposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't be too worried about the cost of the call, but for code clarity you can do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a(100);
    auto a_size = a.size(); 
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        const auto threadId = omp_get_thread_num();

        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < a_size; ++i) {
            a[i] = threadId;
        }
    }
}
```

As long as you use `#pragma omp for` (and don't put an extra `parallel in there! otherwise each of your n threads will spawn n more threads... that's bad) it will ensure that inside your parallel region that for loop is split up amongst the n threads. Make sure omp compiler flag is turned on.

Comment: Thanks that works. I use `#pragma omp for simd` in my actual code because I worry that autovectorization wouldn't happen without `simd` in the `#pragma`. Is omp_get_thread_num() slower than a variable look up? (I guess probably it is that case because libomp is a shared library.)